# How to Add an NSMutableIndexSet to Another?

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSMutableIndexSet` and I want to add indexes in it to another `NSMutableIndexSet` in my loop.

I've been looking for right functions but unable to find anything.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
 [someIndexSet addIndexes:otherIndexSet]
```